# Add DEFAULT constraint with a generated name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, default-value

In SQL Server I have an existing table. Now I want to add a DEFAULT constraint to one of the columns - **without having to define a name for it**.

```
-- generated name works fine when creating new column
ALTER TABLE [xyz]
ADD [newColumn] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

-- when adding a default value afterwards I seem to have to provide a name
ALTER TABLE [xyz]
ADD CONSTRAINT [iDontWantToPutANameHere] DEFAULT 0 FOR [existingColumn]
```

Comment: When you add a constraint like you did in the first example sql server will generate a name for that constraint on its own. And the name it generates is not human friendly. The point is that every single constraint MUST have a name. You could alter the column to avoid naming your constraint. However, I would suggest that you should name your constraints. It is never a bad thing to be explicit with your sql objects.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent way to add more work for yourself in the future. Removing a constraint when you know it's name? Trivial. Removing it when you've let the system generate the name - well, first you have to locate it (and make sure you've found the right one), then you have to generate dynamic SQL to actually action the removal. Lovely.

Comment: "It is never a bad thing to be explicit with your sql objects." not true! In an ETL environment, you may want to keep a _prev version of the table. If your table has constraints and you name them, then you have to rename the constraints on the _prev table before you can create them again on the new table. This is hassle, but on our systems it has become a critical issue, as other important processes periodically fail due to the exclusive lock required on the old table to rename the constraints. The solution? Don't explicitly name constraints, then you don't need to touch the live table at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create default constraint for an existing column, without specifying its name, e.g.:

```
create table test
(
    existing_column int
)

alter table test
    add default 0 for existing_column
```

However, there are plenty articles, suggesting that it is better to name constraints explicitly. Because of it is harder to drop or other way alter system-named constraint. Also if you have multiple instances of the same database, the default name will no be the same across them.

Comment: Yes, it works in MSSQL 2019 (and most likely a few versions before) and it correctly generates default constraint name. The only difference is that if you script the table with such a constraint, then it will still come up with `alter table test add default 0 for existing_column` not with `create table test (existing_column int default (0))`. This will be an issue if you need to use some automated tool, like SSDT to perform schema comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the only way you can add a default constraint to an existing column is by naming it.

If it's THAT important to you to get a system-generated name, you can do this:

1. Alter Table adding new column with un-named DEFAULT value.
2. Update Table, setting the values of the new column to the values of the old column.
3. Drop the old column.
4. Rename the new column to the name of the old column.

Personally I wish that SQL Server didn't give any option for not naming your constraints.  I hate dealing with the system generated names that some lazy developer left behind.